# How to check in Bash if there is a file with an asterisk it its name

Tags: bash-scripting, filenames

I've got an error in a Bash script that creates files with an asterisk ("*") in the name.  I do not want this, so I'm trying to test at various points in the script if such a thing exists yet, so that I can find out where it is happening.  I keep stumbling over this and have not yet found a robust (and short) way to do it.

If I was looking for letters like 'z', I could use

```bash
    for i in *z*; do
      if [ ${i/z/} != '*z*' ] ; then
        echo Found one
        break
      fi
    done
```

But if I try that with an asterisk, I get in trouble: it appears that any occurrence of "*" after the "in" causes all filenames to be concatenated, whether or not any of them contains an asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

Any glob wildcard can be turned back into a literal character by prefixing it with a backslash or protecting it from the shell by placing it in quotes:

```
ls -d -- *\**
ls -d -- *'*'*

rm -i -- *\**
```

Note that `find` handles globs in its `-name` action itself, so even though the string might (and should) be quoted to protect it from the shell, you still would need a backslash to protect it from `find`:

```
find . -name '*\**' -print
```

If you want a nice report you can either loop over matches or have `find` deliver them directly

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *\**
do
    printf "Found file with wildcard: '%s'\n" "$i"
done
```

or

```
find -name '*\**' -printf Found file with wildcard: '%P'\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Right after composing this question, I found a workable answer

```
for i in *; do
  if [ "${i/\*/}" != "$i" ] ; then
    echo found one in $i;
  fi;
done
```

If any filename contains an asterisk, $i will be the concatenation of all of them, but it works because of the quotes in the if-condition.

Comment: It's good that you found a solution. However you don't need a loop - you can let the shell do the heavy lifting for you

Answer (score 1):

A simple `ls | fgrep '*'` gives you the list of filenames with a `*` inside.

If you just want to know if a such file exists: `ls | fgrep -q '*' && echo Found`